# Why can I see o, io, nio threads in my Spring Boot logs?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlet-3.0

I run a test case in my springboot project (base version 2.1.0.R and tomcat 9 in web-starter) ：

```
@RequestMapping("test")
public String test() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    logger.info(Thread.activeCount()+"");
    return "";
}
```

and then I send many concurrent request(more than 300 requests at almost same time).in this log：

2020-03-21 10:53:19.866  INFO 33092 --- [nio-8080-exec-4]                                          : 209

2020-03-21 10:53:19.868  INFO 33092 --- [o-8080-exec-111]                                          : 209

2020-03-21 10:53:19.869  INFO 33092 --- [io-8080-exec-62]                                          : 209

2020-03-21 10:53:19.870  INFO 33092 --- [io-8080-exec-70]                                          : 209

In my options ,I can only see nio threads in it due to Tomcat 9, so I can't unterstand this log. I want to know why.

Sorry for my poor English leavel.
[log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyqjY.png)

Comment: It looks like the logger is displaying the last 15 characters of the thread name.  Look at the logger configs.

Comment: o thanks，looks like I asked a stupid question ≦(._.)≧